# terraform state mv for ssm parameters

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to move 5 ssm parameters for one state file to another, having had to rename the statefile due to a naming conflict with another repo. The statefiles are listing below:

Source:

```
production/productionqa/10_app_params_init/terraform.tfstate
```

Destination:

```
production/productionqa/portal/10_app_params_init/terraform.tfstate
```

I'm adding portal to the path.

Now I need to move an SSM parameter:

```
aws_ssm_parameter.app_parmaters_auto["/config/common/hubspot/email_id_invitation"]
```

As I understand, I need to specify SOURCE then RESOURCE then DESTINATION

The terraform command I'm using is :

```
terraform state mv -dry-run production/productionqa/10_app_params_init/terraform.tfstate aws_ssm_parameter.app_parmaters_auto["/config/common/hubspot/email_id_signup"] production/productionqa/portal/10_app_params_init/terraform.tfstate
```

I'm getting an error of:

```
no matches found: aws_ssm_parameter.app_parmaters_auto[/config/common/hubspot/email_id_signup]
```

I know that the `app_parmaters_auto` is misspelt but that how terraform outputs it.

I wondered if anyone knows the correct syntax for moving SSM parameters as I can't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Can you add the part of code where the SSM parameter is created to the question? I'm pretty sure the part in the square brackets is incorrect, but without the resource block it's hard to answer.

Comment: And no, the command is (from the docs): `terraform state mv [options] SOURCE DESTINATION`. No mention of `RESOURCE`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding quotes '' in your source and destination addresses.
I got same issue and adding quotes did it for me.

Comment: this is comment and not an answer